# Use Office 365 user directory in Azure

Tags: azure, office365

We have a production Azure account (we currently login to this with Microsoft IDs created using our company email addresses).

We now have Office 365, with all our users added to the Azure Active Directory included with Office 365 - how can we use our Office 365 credentials to login to our existing Azure account? E.g. is there a way to replace the old Azure directory with the new one Office 365 created as part of Office 365?

There seems to be a process to do this using the classic Azure portal, but it's not clear how/if this can be done with the new portal.

Comment: please have a look at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/azure-integration and let me known if it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch the AAD in Azure from the new portal.
In order to do this, the steps are similar to this:

Lets imagine you have tenant currently associated with your Azure subscription named @test.onmicrosoft.com and you would like to switch it for @prod.onmicrosoft.com
Let's imagine you have two accounts, one is a global admin over the current tenant admin@test.onmicrosoft.com and the other admin over the new tenant you would like to use admin@prod.onmicrosoft.com

1. Log in your Azure subscription with the admin user admin@test.onmicrosoft.com domain.
2. On the subscription level, add a user admin@prod.onmicrosoft.com as a co-administrator. You are inviting this user as "external user" over the subscription
3. The user admin@prod.onmicrosoft.com will get an email which inviting him to the AAD. Optionally (if you don't have a mailbox license) you can search for the admin@prod.onmicrosoft.com user in AAD @test.onmicrosoft.com and copy the activation link you can find in the user profile.
4. Accept the invite or the activation link login with the user admin@prod.onmicrosoft.com. You will log in to the tenant with the new user.
5. Go to the subscription and "change directory".

[Change directory in subscription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxmVi.png)

I hope this helps!